# AS3 Replay movie including symbols?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, timeline, scene

I happen to have lots symbols with timelines, if I gotoAndPlay frame 1 from scene 1, most symbols  won't play like they did on the first time.

I use

```
MovieClip(root).gotoAndPlay("one");
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason they're not playing is due to the fact that they have their own timeline, if you want every single one of your MovieClip to play, use the following function:

```
function playEverything(disp : DisplayObjectContainer, frame : int = 1) : void
{
    if(disp is MovieClip)
    {
        MovieClip(disp).gotoAndPlay(frame);
    }
    for(var i : int = 0; i < disp.numChildren; i++)
    {
        var child : DisplayObject = disp.getChildAt(i);
        if(child is DisplayObjectContainer)
        {
            playEverything(DisplayObjectContainer(child), frame);
        }
    }
}
```

Then to play everything, do `playEverything(stage);`